# Granger Causality Test in R / Measure Effect of iterations & Multivariate

Tags: r, testing, statistics

I am checking for Granger Causility in my model. If I run this test in R, results are significant:

```
grangertest(Hostility_3 ~ Total, order = 4, data = Trade)
```

Now, in order to measure the effect of the four iterations of Total on Hostility3, I create a new variable that contains a moving average of Total over the past four time periods:

```
Trade <- Trade %>%
     mutate(
         Moving_Average_4_Total = rollmean(Total, k = 4, fill = NA)
     )
```

When testing for granger causality between the new variable and Hostility3, however, my results are not significant. How can I measure the effect of these four iterations of Total on Hostility3?

Also, I tried to conduct a granger causality test including my controls but this does not appear to work and it appears as if the r command grangertest can only conduct a granger test with two variables. Is there no way to include my controls though?

I am trying to measure the effect of the four iterations of my Total variable. By constructing a moving average of the past 4 iterations, I hoped to achieve right this